Azure App Service Plan Consumes 70% of Memory Without Deploying Any Code
In Azure, I have created an App Service Plan (ASP) and a web app using Node.js 20 as the runtime stack with Linux as the operating system. This web app has no code deployed yet. Once I mapped this web app to the ASP, the ASP shows 70% memory usage.
ASP configuration

Could someone please explain why this memory is being consumed? Thanks in advance

What is the app service tier you are using. @Shanthi B

Free F1 ASP plan

Updated below clearly. Can you check and let me know. @Shanthi B

Sure I'll check, thanks


This web app has no code deployed yet. Once I mapped this web app to the ASP, the ASP shows 70% memory usage.

"Azure App service is showing 70% of memory usage though you have not deployed any code yet".
The memory usage issue can occur due to different factors. As you mentioned you are using Linux runtime, once you define and create an app service with Linux runtime, memory will be used by Linux processors as it starts handling various SCM console operations and also security updates, authentication operations too.
Also check whether the app service plan has been allocated to any other apps which may leads to consuming high memory usage.
An easy way to check this is visiting Diagnose and solve problems under an app service.
Check for Memory Analysis under Availability and performance as shown below.

The above chart shows you the app usage and app service plan usage consumption in terms of bytes.
Now for a clear vision of byte wise app and app plan usage, visit Memory Drill Down under Memory Analysis, it helps you to
check the per instance memory Drill Down of each app allocated to an app service plan.


Also check any continuous deployments or background jobs are running in the platform which consumes the memory capacity.
As there is no node.js code deployed yet, nothing can be from node.js side. The issue is with the app service plan only. Check above steps to find out the issue.
If still the issue persists, try scaling up the tier of an app service plan and change the operations accordingly.
